# XSLT multiple matching templates for given path

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to apply all matching templates to a node but it seems like always only one is applied depending on the order of templates in my XSLT file. Here is minimal example:

```
<!-- XML Source -->
<a>
    <b url="foo">
      <text>1</text>
      <text>2</text>
    </b>
</a>

<!-- XSL transformation -->
<!-- Transform1 -->
<xsl:template match="//*[text]">
    <xsl:for-each select="text">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Transform2 -->
<xsl:template match="//*[@url]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So the result I am expecting is `12foo` but written like this it only matches the Transfor1 template and if I swap the order it only matches the Transform2 template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processor first looks at the priority https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#conflict and if there is more than one with the same priority it can either report an error or choose the last one.

So you will have to redesign your code and either use modes to distinguish your processing steps and apply-templates in the modes you want to use or in XSLT 2 or later you could test whether using `<xsl:next-match/>` helps you solve that.

On the other hand, your current code matches on elements to then process the `text` child elements and the `url` attributes, if you simply write template matching `*/text` and another matching `@url` and have `*[text]` or `*[@url]` matching templates do an `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>` you might not have that problem at all.

If you want to output the attribute after the child nodes then in XSLT 1 you need two `apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="b">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpB shows, that suffices to output the values of the elements and the attribute as the built-in templates do that work.

In XSLT 2 or 3 you can shorten the code to

```
  <xsl:template match="b">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text, @*"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpB/1.

As for using `next-match` in your attempt, it would look like

```
<xsl:template match="//*[text]">
    <xsl:for-each select="text">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*[@url]">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpB/2

Comment: I'm trying to implement what you suggested but I can't seem to get it working. Could you provide a working example? Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question first and show us the result you want to create for that input you have shown.

Comment: I've used something similar to your first example and it works nicely. The only difference is that the `b` element can have different names therefore the template matches `//*[@url|text]`. Thanks for the examples.